# Finding 1 unknown in simlutaneus equations with 3 unknowns and 2 equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

**Background**

I am working with imaging data and I have computed what are called Haralick features that measure the "texture" of an image. It is common in my field to measure the features in the x direction (left/right) and the y direction (up/down), but for this you get different answers if you rotate the image and then measure again. I am investigating this "rotational invariance".

I have simulated measuring these haralick features on images and rotations of those images. It looks like each haralick feature has a "true" value, just when I measure it in the x direction I get the "true" value plus a sine wave and in the y direction I get the true value plus a cosine wave. I am trying to work out if given just the values of a  haralick feature in the x and y direction at one specific rotation, can I calculate the "true" value?

**The Problem**

The problem simplifies to something like this. I have two equations

$$x = \mu + \alpha\sin(\theta)$$
$$y = \mu + \alpha\cos(\theta)$$

If I know the value of $x$ and $y$ but I don't know $\mu$, $\alpha$ or $\theta$, is it possible to use $x$ and $y$ to work out just $\mu$?

Normally you can't solve 2 equations with 3 unknowns but I only want to solve for one of them. I am guessing the solution will involve transforming the equations to be in terms of $\mu$ and some dummy variable $\phi$, where $\phi$ is a function of $\alpha$ and $\theta$. Then it would be possible to solve for 2 unknowns with 2 equations but I can't work out how to do this in this case.

Comment: All you know is that $(\mu-x)^2+(\mu-y)^2=\alpha^2$, so the question is *I have a circle of known center and unknown radius, can I find its intersection(s) with the main bisector*? The answer is no, unless you have additional information.